# Do any issues arise if multiple tomcat instances have common webapps folder by using links?

Tags: java, tomcat

I am actually planning a setup of creating load balancing between tomcat instances (for almost 3 instances) using apache httpd and mod_jk. I am hosting almost 10 (common) apps in each instance.

The contents of the applications are placed at a location and I created the links in each of the tomcat instances pointing to the application contents. This is well and good.

But my concern here is, whenever I am using the links of the applications, I need to extract the war file and need to place the extracted content in the application content location. Is it not possible to create the links for the folder "webapps" in each instance and place the "webapps" along with its inside content at some other location? Does any issue arise because of this causes my tomcat misbehave?

Please suggest. Thanks in advance.